Estimate time spent by ships in each grid using ArcGIS Pro
I have data on yearly ship movements in an area. The area is divided into 1km x 1km grids.
The yearly ship movements are available in the form of tracks which are polylines. The tracks feature class has the average speed as one of the fields.
I am now looking to estimate the time spent by ships in each 1km x 1km grid using ArcGIS Pro.
From what I could see, using something similar to Line Density could be helpful to do the above, but I cannot get to a full workable solution. I am fairly new to ArcGIS Pro.
As per https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-line-density-works.htm, the line density considers the length of each line falling within a circle drawn (with search radius as the radius) around the center of each raster cell. Further, the length of the portion of each line that falls within the circle is multiplied by its Population field value.
I can set the “Population” field to be “1/Average Speed”. Multiplying the length of the line portion with “1/Average Speed” for each line, summing all contributions and multiplying by the area of the search circle will give a line density value per grid that will correspond to an estimate of total time spent by ships in that grid. However, for this approach to work, I would need to estimate Line Density by considering the lengths of all line features within a raster cell, i.e. not within in a circular neighborhood around the raster cell but just within the exact boundaries of the raster cell.
Is there any way of using Line Density in ArcGIS Pro by considering just the raster cell or are there other ways to solve my original problem, i.e. estimate time spent by ships in each grid?

Try setting search radius to 1/2 pixel size (or 1/2 pixel diagonal/hypotenuse size)

@user2856 I did earlier try the 1st option you suggested but that would still mean the circle area (which is what Line Density uses) and the grid area are not the same.

Another approach, assuming your 1km grid is a vector polygon dataset is to use the Intersect tool. The output is a new line dataset cut up by the grid but also tagged by grid ID. So now you have the track length of every ship tagged with an grid cell ID. Compute your time spent in cell field then for example run that through the summary statistics tool if say you wanted total time spent by all ships within a grid cell. Finally you simply join the table by grid ID back to the grid and visualise however.

Thanks for this. I will implement this and return with an update on how it worked.

I now implemented this and it works fine. @Hornbydd - thanks again for your approach. I made one minor update - instead of Intersect, I used Pairwise Intersect for my problem, as according to https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/how-pairwise-intersect-works.htm, Pairwise Intersect offers better performance than Intersect.
